# Integration of SharePoint 2010 with TFS2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, team-foundation-server

We have performed following steps as of now-

1. Install TFS2010 10.0.30319.1 (RTM) on Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise(app tier)
2. SQL 2008 SP1 with Cumulative update 2 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise(data tier)
3. Reporting Service is installed on app tier.
4. After this installation worked fine we installed SharePoint 2010 on app tier.
5. After installation we followed [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151223133550/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/team_foundation/archive/2010/03/06/configuring-sharepoint-server-2010-beta-for-dashboard-compatibility-with-tfs-2010-beta2-rc.aspx)
   for configuration.
6. We are not able to perform the last step described in the link as following error occured-
   TF249063: The following Web service is not available: http://apptier:31254/_vti_bin/TeamFoundationIntegrationService.asmx. This Web service is used for the Team Foundation Server Extensions for SharePoint Products. The underlying error is: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.. Verify that the following URL points to a valid SharePoint Web application and that the application is available: http://apptier:31254. If the URL is correct and the Web application is operating normally, verify that a firewall is not blocking access to the Web application.
7. We have also noticed that Document Folder in Team project also have red x.

Please help.
Thanks upfront.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're trying to add MOSS to TFS post installation of TFS? Did you try this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tfssetup/archive/2010/10/04/tf249063-the-following-web-service-is-not-available.aspx

Comment: I follwed the correct sequence of installation- 1.Install SQL 2008, SP1 and Cumulative Update 2.Install SharePoint 2010 and congiure according to -blogs.msdn.com/b/team_foundation/archive/2010/03/06/… 3.Install TFS2010 and Sharepoint web extensions and it works.

Answer (score 0):

From the 'Solution Management' area of SharePoint Central Admin (e.g. 'http://myserver:5555/_admin/Solutions.aspx'), you should see the following entries:

- microsoft.teamfoundation.sharepoint.dashboards.wsp
- microsoft.teamfoundation.sharepoint.wsp
- tswawebpartcollection.wsp

They should all be in a 'deployed' state.

If they are missing then this probably points to a wider installation issue, however, you could try uploading and installing them into SharePoint manually.  The .WSP files should be available in the 'Tools\Template' folder under the main TFS installation directory.

This is best done via PowerShell from a 'SharePoint 2010 Management Shell', using the *Add-SPSolution* and *Install-SPSolution* cmdlets. (see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262995.aspx for more info on using these)

Cheers,
James.

Comment: I have implemented following on a test(Data tier, app tier in same server) environment and it works. 

1.Install SQL 2008, SP1 and Cumulative Update

2.Install SharePoint 2010 and congiure according to -http://blogs.msdn.com/b/team_foundation/archive/2010/03/06/configuring-sharepoint-server-2010-beta-for-dashboard-compatibility-with-tfs-2010-beta2-rc.aspx

3.Install TFS2010 and Sharepoint web extensions